# How do I specify language when using OpenAI's Whisper's Python library? And where is its the documentation?

Tags: python, documentation, openai-whisper, api-documentation

How do I specify language when using OpenAI's Whisper's Python library? I can do it when I use the command line client using `--language`. How do I achieve the same result when using Whisper as a Python library?

And where can I find documentation for the Whisper Python library so I don't need to ask extremely basic questions like this? When I google I only find API-documentation for running Whisper on OpenAI's servers but I am running it locally. I am new to the Python community and am expecting/looking for something similar to Java's Javadoc, especially in big and complicate project like Whisper. Doesn't the Python community document their libraries etc?